# Retrieve outer key from list of objects with child objects

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using fetch to retrieve a json file. The json file returns a list of objects. Each object also has an object. I am trying to console log the outer object. The below is the contents of the file. From the below data, I'm trying to log this list ['CNDNET','Acropolis','Other']. If I use Object.keys(data) I get a list of integers [0,1,2]. Thank you.

```
[
   {
      "CNDNET":{
         "application":[
            {
               "Elastic":[
                  "Missing Data",
                  "No Data/Data Feed Down",
                  "Content/Feature Request",
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Kibana":[
                  "Website Access Issue",
                  "Access Issue",
                  "Site Down"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Logstash":[
                  "Missing Data",
                  "No Data/Data Feed Down",
                  "Content/Feature Request",
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Kafka":[
                  "Missing Data",
                  "No Data/Data Feed Down",
                  "Content/Feature Request",
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Phoenix":[
                  "Missing Data",
                  "No Data/Data Feed Down",
                  "Content/Feature Request",
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Outlook":[
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Domain Account":[
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Token":[
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Software":[
                  "Authenticate",
                  "Firefox",
                  "Swift"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Hardware":[
                  "Monitor",
                  "Printer"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "Acropolis":{
         "application":[
            {
               "ACT":[
                  "Missing Data",
                  "No Data/Data Feed Down",
                  "Content/Feature Request",
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "ARTEMIS":[
                  "Missing Data",
                  "No Data/Data Feed Down",
                  "Content/Feature Request",
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "Other":{
         "application":[
            {
               "CMIS":[
                  "Website Access Issue",
                  "Other",
                  "Access Issue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "SharePoint":[
                  "Access Issue",
                  "Other"
               ]
            },
            {
               "GTMS":[
                  "Access Issue",
                  "Other"
               ]
            },
            {
               "Other":[
                  "Other"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: you're calling `keys` on an array which is returning the indexes of the outer `data` array (0,1,2)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually three objects contained in the top level `data` array. You can use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to iterate through these, returning the `Object.keys()` for each.

```js
const data = [{ "CNDNET": { "application": [{ "Elastic": ["Missing Data", "No Data/Data Feed Down", "Content/Feature Request", "Access Issue"] }, { "Kibana": ["Website Access Issue", "Access Issue", "Site Down"] }, { "Logstash": ["Missing Data", "No Data/Data Feed Down", "Content/Feature Request", "Access Issue"] }, { "Kafka": ["Missing Data", "No Data/Data Feed Down", "Content/Feature Request", "Access Issue"] }, { "Phoenix": ["Missing Data", "No Data/Data Feed Down", "Content/Feature Request", "Access Issue"] }, { "Outlook": ["Access Issue"] }, { "Domain Account": ["Access Issue"] }, { "Token": ["Access Issue"] }, { "Software": ["Authenticate", "Firefox", "Swift"] }, { "Hardware": ["Monitor", "Printer"] }] } }, { "Acropolis": { "application": [{ "ACT": ["Missing Data", "No Data/Data Feed Down", "Content/Feature Request", "Access Issue"] }, { "ARTEMIS": ["Missing Data", "No Data/Data Feed Down", "Content/Feature Request", "Access Issue"] }] } }, { "Other": { "application": [{ "CMIS": ["Website Access Issue", "Other", "Access Issue"] }, { "SharePoint": ["Access Issue", "Other"] }, { "GTMS": ["Access Issue", "Other"] }, { "Other": ["Other"] }] } }]

const dataKeys = data.flatMap(o => Object.keys(o));

console.log(dataKeys);
```

As noted in my comment, calling `Object.keys()` directly on the the `data` array simply returns the integer indexes of the array. ([0,1,2])

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your array and return the keys and store it in a variable. Later, either use `concat()` or `flat()` method to convert 2D array to 1D array as shown below through example.

```
let result = arr.map((item) => {
  return Object.keys(item)
})

console.log(result.flat())
console.log([].concat(...result))
```